# move_arm_warehouse package error

Tags: ros, move-arm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do you you use Arm Navigation Warehouse viewer on Ros electric? I tried to run rosrun move_arm_warehouse create_launch_files.py pr2_test from the Iros2011 motion planning Tutorials and it return this error message: ([rospack] couldn't find package [move_arm_warehouse]). Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12341/move_arm_warehouse-package-error/) by [OptiX](https://answers.ros.org/users/1535/optix/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2011-12-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-02-23**:
Maybe you can try 'sudo apt-get install ros-electric-*'. I can roscd to that package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks Sam I hadn't all installed all the dependencies yet now the problem is solved.

---

Originally posted by [OptiX](https://answers.ros.org/users/1535/optix/) with karma: 63 on 2012-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0